# How to get strftime 7 hours in the past?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, timestamp, strftime

I have a timestamp that is in a time zone 7 hours ahead of me. The timestamp is saved in the `strftime` format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`. How do I make this timestamp go 7 hours back?

Example: Timestamp right now: `2014-4-14 3:00`. What I want: `2014-4-13 20:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the following if I have a datetime.  Are you saying you only have string to work with?

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

expires = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(hours=7)
```

Comment: Yes, but I found a way to incorporate it. Thanks! (+1'ed and will be accepted in 5 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> str(datetime.strptime('2014-4-14 3:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') + \
      timedelta(hours = -7))
'2014-04-13 20:00:00'

>>> datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=-7),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2014-04-13 14:45'
```